# Choice of companies where to work: is medium of age important?

Tags: company-culture

I am a 35 year old web developer who recently worked on two companies where things did not go as I expected.

In one company I stayed almost four years, and in 40 people, only two others were of similar age to mine. Only in the last 6 months they mention that my performance decreased and so they negotiated my exit. I think that it is true because my second daughter was born, and I was more tired.

In the next company of 40 people, only I was this age. The rest, a few had about 30 years old, and the others were all younger.

In the second company they mentioned that my performance was below expectations. In this one, I switched to a new technology that I had not developed for around four years.

What I felt in these two companies was that I no longer have the dynamic of the younger people, nor the availability to work more hours to technically follow all the changes and evolutions that are happening.

So, what do you guys think? Do you think that older guys who code choose smaller companies, where there are fewer large-scale comparisons and less competition? Or is this a wrong assumption?

Comment: Question will probably be closed, as it is strongly opinion-based (do you think + personal questions). I would suggest rewording it to allow for more objective answers.

Comment: I will say that, in some companies, I have seen not *age* discrimination (because that would be illegal in the USA, wink wink), but experience-based discrimination.  Due to my number of years of experience, they had more leadership expectations of me rather than technical skills.  I have since moved on to a new company that appreciates my technical experience, and my "work smarter not harder" attitude.

Comment: My experience is the opposite-  people who want to coast take jobs at big companies where they can hide.  People who want to work hard go to smaller companies.  This is a trend regardless of age (although with plenty of exceptions).

Answer (score 5):

Age seems less of an issue than performance. Most workplaces will have people of varying ages. Performance is usually the criteria people are judged on, and to an extent social interactions within the workplace.

In your case performance is the only factor I see that is an issue.

Comment: Exactly, you're older, and presumably more experienced and expensive. You're noticing that you're the oldest, that generally means the most experienced, and that generally means the highest expectations. Priority #1 with any new job should be to understand what their expectations are and how you can meet them.

Answer (score 2):

> [Originally asked] Do you think I'm picking the wrong companies?

There's no real way for us to tell.

> What I felt in these two companies was that I no longer have the
>   dynamic of the younger people, nor the availability to work more hours
>   to technically follow all the changes and evolutions that are
>   happening.

Then perhaps you should try a different type of company that won't require you to work extra hours, and won't tax you technically.

Your problems might be the age of the other employees, but it might just be your abilities and your performance. Trying a different type of company might help you find out.

Before I retired, I was the oldest employee at my location. I never had performance problems and I never had issues keeping up with new technologies. Some of us can be lifelong learners, some cannot.